# Bessel's correction demonstration

Tags: self-study, variance, bessels-correction

I am currently trying to understand the proof of the Bessel's correction [Proof of correctness 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Proof_of_correctness_-_Alternate_3) and there is one step in the demonstration that I do not understand:

$$
\operatorname{Var}(\bar x) = \frac{\sigma^2} n
$$

When we admit that:

$$
\operatorname{Var}(x) = \sigma^2 \text{ and } \bar x = \operatorname{E}(x)
$$

If anyone can clarify this step I would really appreciate.

**UPDATE**

I am stuck at the point where:

$$
\operatorname{Var}(\bar x) = \operatorname{E} \left(\left(\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i} n - \mu\right)^2\right) = \frac 1 {n^2} \operatorname{E} \left( \left( \sum_{i=0}^n x_i - n\mu\right)^2\right)
$$

Comment: $\bar x$ does not stand for $E(x)$: it is the arithmetic mean of the $n$ data.  Because the data are assumed independent, the formula for the mean and basic properties of the variance combine to prove this equality.

Comment: So you get $Var(\bar x) = E((\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{x_i}}{n} - \mu)^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, but how ?

Comment: The appropriate statement would be $E[\bar{x}]=E[x]$. You should consider adding the [self study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag, and update the question to show what you know and where you are stuck.

Comment: True that was a wrong shortcut for $\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i$. I will update the question.

Comment: It is immediate by computing $$\operatorname{Var}(\bar x)=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}x_1+\frac{1}{n}x_2+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}x_n\right).$$

Comment: Ok thanks, I decomposed too much and got stuck. Your answer is clear and simple. If by any chance you could also tell me with my approach how I could have found the same answer, I would appreciate since it would help me better understand how to work with variance.

Comment: By the way, your Wikipedia link goes to "Proof 3". If you instead go to "Proof 2", then the equation $\mathrm{Var}(\bar{x})=\sigma^2/n$ is *immediately followed* by the sentence: "This is a property of the variance of uncorrelated variables, arising from the [Bienaymé formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29)." Did you check that link?

Comment: I missed it previously but that is basically the same answer as @whuber. It is a correct and clear one. I am just wondering if the path I had chosen to try to prove it is correct and then if you knew what I could have done to finish the demonstration this way. Consider it a bonus :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to show is this:
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} n - \mu = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - n\mu).
$$

In subtracting fractions, use a common denominator:
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} n - \mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} n - \frac{n\mu} n = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - n\mu} n
$$
This is $\dfrac 1 n \left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) - n\mu\right).$

Next, apply an identity concerning variances:
$$
\operatorname{var}\left( \frac 1 n Y \right) = \frac 1 {n^2} \operatorname{var}(Y).
$$

Comment: The step I was stuck in is just after where you stop. How can you go from $\frac{1}nvar(Y)$ to $\frac{\sigma^2}n$. That means that $var(Y) = n\sigma^2$ however I do not see how.

Comment: @YohanObadia : $$ \operatorname{var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - n\mu) \right) = \operatorname{var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2 = n\sigma^2. $$ The second equality follows from independence of $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n. \qquad$

Comment: The independence of the $x_i$ allows to move from the second member to the third, but how do you get from the first member to the second ? I mean, from $\operatorname{var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - n\mu) \right)$ to  $\operatorname{var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)$